# filter data from one List of dictionaries to another

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries in file. And I want to see if the keys FLOW, PROTOCOL and PROT are with the same value in whole list of dictionary. Then in another function, I want to check the value of field STYPE and DTYPE.

example of how my list of dictionary in file look like

```
dict= [
       {
          "FLOW":"Blue-Yellow",
          "PROTOCOL":"TCP",
          "PROT":22,
          "STYPE":"AB",
          "DTYPE":"Hu1"
       },
       {
          "FLOW":"Blue-Yellow",
          "PROTOCOL":"TCP",
          "PROT":22,
          "STYPE":"HU1",
          "DTYPE":"AB"
       },
```

need to check if the FLOW, PROTOCOL, PROT are same

then need to check value of field STYPE and DTYPE

```
if  "STYPE":"HU1","DTYPE":"AB"
and "STYPE":"AB","DTYPE":"HU1"
```

then

need create a 2 new dict with same FLOW, PROTOCOL, PROT.

But the "STYPE":"HU1","DTYPE":"HU1" and for other "STYPE":"AB","DTYPE":"AB" we need a separate function

```
for line in open('list-dict.txt', 'r'): 
    rec = line.strip() print(rec)

def make_value_key(d, list_of_keys): 
    res = "" 
    for k in list_of_keys: 
        res += str(d[k]) return res
```

I wrote this code to read file line by line, now need to filter list of dictionary based on criteria stated above.

the expected output should be displaying the result in list of dictionary format